# angular activatedRoute params TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I try to navigate from a company Detail component to company Edit component with
`company.id` parameter.

Navigating from company List component to company Detail component works, but when I try to do the same from company Detail to Company Edit,

`<button (click)="editCompany(company.id)">edit</button>` 
   it shows an error:

> ERROR Type Error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

when I hardcode the id on the button in company Detail.html like this:
      `<button (click)="editCompany(4)">edit</button>`

it successfully navigates to company Edit, e.g with company `id =4` binding the Form.

Can someone explain why `(click)="editCompany(company.id)"` in companyDetail.html does not work the same way as the button click in companyList.html?

Code snippeds:

```
companyDetail(id: number): void {
    this.router.navigate(['company-detail', id]);
}
```

companyDetail.html

```
   <div *ngIf="company$ | async as c; else loading">
       Id: {{c.id}}, Name: {{c.companyName}}
   </div>
   <button (click)="editCompany(company.id)">edit</button>
```

companyDetail.ts

```
editCompany(id: number): void {
    this.router.navigate(['company-edit', id]);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were binding the result to the value of `c` so `c.id` should work, if I assume your `ngif` condition is true. Also, you were ending the div tag before button and `(click)=editCompany(4)` working is because you were not binding anything there.

```
 <div *ngIf="company$ | async as c; else loading">
  Id: {{c.id}}, Name: {{c.companyName}}
 <button (click)="editCompany(c.id)">edit</button>`
 </div>
```

Comment: </div> tag and (comapny.id) are the problems. thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax):

> The text between the braces is often the name of a component property.
>   Angular replaces that name with the string value of the corresponding
>   component property.
>
> More generally, the text between the braces is a template expression
>   that Angular first evaluates and then converts to a string.

and as per this line  `company$ | async as c` you are alias  company value as c,
so you can't access company value directly like this  `company.id` you a can access company value with 'c' which you assign as

```
<button (click)="editCompany(c.id)">edit</button>
```

Hope this will help !
Cheers

Comment: I change the code to `<button (click)="editCompany(c.id)">edit</button>` it has same error. thanks for answer anyway.